# According to Catholicism did God conspire with Satan to kill Job’s children?

Tags: catholicism, satan, job

Did Satan and God have a conversation in which Satan says he wants to bring harm to Job’s family and then God provides Satan with permission to do so. And then Satan kills Job’s children!

Comment: "Did Satan and God have a conversation ....." Yes they did. It is recorded in the book of Job. I am unclear as to what you are actually asking.

Comment: @curiousdannii I thought maybe she died too. I’ll update the question.

Comment: @NigelJ I just wanted to know if it was actually in the bible, from someone who read it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's still functionally a verse search question, even though it is scoped to Catholicism.

Comment: I believe that this question in on topic because it requires Catholic sources to answer it.

Comment: @KenGraham  look through the edits and comments. The catholic POV was edited in simply as a bandaid as can be seen from the self answer given that has no catholic sourcing

Comment: If God did not intend to kill Jobs children God could have restored them to life, God did not restore them. God employed Satan an agent of evil to kill Jobs children and then left them dead.

Answer (score 1):

**According to Catholicism did God conspire with Satan to kill Jobs children?**

The short answer is **no**.

While God and Satan did have a conversation about Job, God did not did not conspire with Satan to kill the children of Job.

To start with let us look at what the definition of what is it to conspire:

> [**Definition of conspire**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conspire)
>
> 1 a: join in a secret agreement to do an unlawful or wrongful act or an act which becomes unlawful as a result of the secret agreement
>
> b : SCHEME
>
> 2 : to act in harmony toward a common end

In the Roman Catholic Liturgy readings from the [Book of Job](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Job) are read during Matins in the first two weeks of September and in the Office of the Dead, and in the revised Liturgy of the Hours Job is read during the Eighth and Ninth Weeks in Ordinary Time.

That said you will not be able to find a genuine Catholic source to states that God did in fact conspire with Satan to kill Job’s children.

> ‘Very well,' Yahweh said to Satan, 'all he has is in your power. But keep your hands off his person.' So Satan left the presence of Yahweh. - [Job1:12](https://www.catholic.org/bible/book.php?id=22)

God did give permission to Satan to test his servant Job, but He did not conspire with the Evil One. There was a conversation between the two and Satan received the permission to inflict Job with various evils.

To give someone [permission](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/permission) to do do something is a very different than conspiring with someone to do something. Permission in this case simply “to allow”.

Comment: This is an interesting answer, if God would give permission to an agent he knows to be an “Evil One” to test his servant. Is this “test” not just a euphemism for carry out evil acts? Imagine I can employ anyone on earth to do my bidding and I chose a megalomaniac serial killer, do I have no responsibility to chose an agent that has shown they are capable of decent measure and restraint?

Comment: @AndrewRichmond Do not put your place in God’s place. It won’t go so well for you. You, like myself, are merely man.

Comment: Protecting God from criticism is infantalizes God, jesus asks “why have you forsaken me”. I ask why God do you conspire with Satan? Your followers do not respect your true nature if they cannot see that you use agents of evil to do your bidding.